# How to extract entire rows from pandas data frame, if a column's string value contains a specific pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, pattern-matching

I have the following data frame with column 'Name' having a pattern '///' in its values

```
data = [['a1','yahoo', 'apple'], ['a2','gma///il', 'mango'], ['a3','amazon', 'papaya'], 
['a4','bi///ng', 'guava']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Name', 'Info'])
```

I need to extract the entire row from this data frame if the column 'Name' has Value having a pattern '///' in it. I have tried the following code but getting a empty dataframe.

```
new_df = df.loc[df['Name'] == '///']
```

My expected output should give me a data frame like this:

```
data_new = [['a2','gma///il', 'mango'],['a4','bi///ng', 'guava']] 
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Name', 'Info'])  
print(new_df)
```

Comment: `new_df = df[ df['Name'].str.contains('///') ]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Series.str.contains`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['a1','yahoo', 'apple'], ['a2','gma///il', 'mango'],
        ['a3','amazon', 'papaya'],['a4','bi///ng', 'guava']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Name', 'Info'])

print (df[df["Name"].str.contains("///")])

#
   ID      Name   Info
1  a2  gma///il  mango
3  a4   bi///ng  guava
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter on perticular one column then use this solution

```py
import numpy as np
immport pandas as pd

data = [['a1','yahoo', 'apple'], ['a2','gma///il', 'mango'], ['a3','amazon', 'papaya'], 
['a4','bi///ng', 'guava']] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Name', 'Info']) 

mask = np.column_stack([df['Name'].str.contains(r"\///", na=False)]) 
df.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   ID      Name   Info
1  a2  gma///il  mango
3  a4   bi///ng  guava
```

If you need filtering on all columns for some pattern then see the below solution

```py
import numpy as np
mask = np.column_stack([df[col].str.contains(r"\///", na=False) for col in df]) 
df.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   ID      Name   Info
1  a2  gma///il  mango
3  a4   bi///ng  guava
```

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame` has string function `contains()` for this

```
 new_df = df[ df['Name'].str.contains('///') ]
```